# Simplest Twitter authentication

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

What is the very, very simplest method of getting the RSS (or JSONP) feed of a Twitter account's list or friends' timeline?

Here some background: I have a simple server script that feeds a Twitter widget. I wrote the script about two months ago but have not had the chance to deploy it until now. The script fetches the `friends_timeline` of a dummy account whose sole purpose is to combine the "friends" tweets into a single RSS feed (rather than making one request for every "friend"). Simple, lightweight, easy to maintain, light on Twitter's servers; seemed to be a good solution at the time. Well, `friends_timeline` requires authentication and right now the server uses `NetworkCredential` to pull down these RSS feeds. As a lot of you know, in August Twitter will cease to support basic authentication and force march everyone over to OAuth. I've looked through the OAuth documentation and I'm not very happy with Twitter right now.

I'm also hoping to avoid using the Twitterizer framework. That's a lot of code to check and it won't go near our production servers without a thorough code review. I know that reinventing the wheel is a bad thing, but in this case all I want is the wheel, not a race car.

Comment: Twitter has delayed the OAuth switchover to Aug 16, I think.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. For some reason I had it in my head that it was July already. I'll edit my question. It was to have been switched over THIS month, but was delayed due to... the World Cup? I'm not sure I see the connection. In any case, it only delays the inevitable.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to switch early especially since OAuth works so much better for the web, not so much for mobile clients, but there's xAuth for that :) I would suggest you checkout the Twitter Anywhere JavaScript API. It works really well for the 1.0 release, but unfortunately that doesn't have the feature of listing friends timelimes. That feature and a whole lot more are available in the Chirp preview release, which as you said may be problematic for your code-review and its not really recommended for production anyways. But still worth checking out - http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page provides a smallish C# Oauth code: http://oauth.net/code/

Don't hate twitter, it was a good idea.

Comment: Nice! It's certainly smaller than the other frameworks! 

I am a little bitter. I was bitten once before under similar circumstances. I wrote a Flash widget for a friend that pulled his RSS feed. That week, Twitter heard that there was a security risk their `crossdomain.xml` and their fix cut thousands of users (& my friend) off with no warning. Anyone who understands crossdmomain.xml knew that in this case there was no issue, but they panicked & overreacted. It showed them then to be amateurish. And they still are: Their API site STILL shows basic authentication as valid. http://bit.ly/u5ewk

Comment: I've discovered that I can accomplish the same thing without authentication using "lists". Seems to be as flexible as I need. I think, though, that your answer is great (though I still hate Twitter). Thanks for your help! I'll mark this as answered!

Comment: No problem, good i could help. And please don't hate twitter, nobody is perfect.